# Flutter app stuck loading right after splash screen fades away

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

Has anybody had anything similar to this happen with a flutter app build? It works half of the time with log in credentials and when I try to use a different person it starts the loading screen and stays stuck there. I’m using firestore for the Authenticator and the database for the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this means: "I’m using firestore for the Authenticator and the database for the app."  I'm guessing you're just a bit new to firebase.  Check out Net Ninja for some good starter material.  You probably have logic issues in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am very new to this. My first app so I've run into a lot of errors and a lot of headache. I figured out the issue though. I had to create a registration screen within the app because if I tried to manually enter login credentials from my computer into firebase the app wouldn't recognize it. I got it fixed and everything is working now. Thanks again for the suggestion. I'll definitely use that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was wanting to manually enter individuals login credentials from my Mac into firestorm but for some reason it wouldn't recognize it. Created a registration page within the app project and now everything works like it's suppose to.